# How can I link employees, supervisor and director in my database ER model

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-relationship

So some homework where I need to make a ER diagram of a Cruise Ship company. How can I properly model the levels of employees on my ER diagram.

We have regular employees (cleaner, nurse, singer, bartender etc)
We have supervisors (which basically supervisors the employees above)
And we have a cruise director. So how can I model this in a way which doesn't cause data duplication or is done in a poor way? Is there a better way of modeling the different levels of employees.

Employee Entity has these attributes (for now):

- EMPLOYEE_ID
- EMPLOYEE_POSITION (This basically states things like cleaner, nurse or bartender)
- EMPLOYEE_IS_SUPERVISOR (This is a yes or no column. If the column says yes, then they are a supervisor). Each employee is supervised by 1 supervisor.
- EMPLOYEE_IS_DIRECTOR (This is another column which has a yes or no
  range. If it says yes, they are a director). This is basically the main boss on the ship.

[image: Click here to see the ER Diagram picture]

Comment: what have u done so far?

Comment: @Graciano I have actually finished the entire model for the cruise company. I am just wondering if there is a better way of expressing the different levels of employees

Comment: Can you post the ERD?

Comment: @dcreight I can't show you the entire thing since it would be against the rules. Here is the relevant parts http://prntscr.com/ixs30y

In the ship entity, it has an attribute called "EMPLOYEE_ID". That employee is actually the ship director (but I don't know how to state that clearly in the ER Diagram).

Comment: You have only two entities here. Employee and employee job title. If employee can have more than o e job title then many to many relationship

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of a is supervisor or is director you can create some sort of hierarchy of employees based on employee id.  So bartender emp_id 123 reports to supervisor 567 reports to director 894.  That gets rid of the need for a lot of flags.  You will know that if that field is blank you they are a director, if they report to a director they are a supervisor and if they report to a supervisor they are an employee.

Other things that would usually be added to an employee data model would be first_name, last_name, DOB, current_status(active employee, terminated, LOA), hired_date, fired_date... just to name a few.

Comment: Yea, I have all the other attributes, my issue is just for the employee levels. So how would I draw the ER diagram like this? So I create more tables? Because supervisor and director still need other info like name, dob etc

Comment: You probably get this from Scott's answer but I saw you asked about other tables, so maybe you haven't quite followed. You would have a single table for *all* employees (where a supervisor and a director are also employees, which isn't quite how you defined employees) and then the employee records reference others in the same table and the employee type can be inferred as Scott suggested

Comment: @PaulShan  Neil is correct in what i was trying to get across.   In the ER i would just call it Reports_To or simply Supervisor.  It is a nullable field obviously due to the director or higher ups.